# Java Timestamp - Adding five minutes

Tags: java

looking for some help with a bit of Java code i'm working on, i have the following code which prints out the date and time:

```
  Date dNow = new Date( ); // Instantiate a Date object
  SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("MMM d, yyyy k:mm:ss");  // Time at server
```

Result: Mar 15, 2013 10:19:48

I'm creating a javascript counter to work from this number and countdown from 5 minutes.  So i need to add 5 minues to the current date time in Java.

So, if the current date time is: Mar 15, 2013 10:19:48

I need to add 5 minutes to Java so that it prints out: Mar 15, 2013 10:24:48

Any ideas?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Instead of starting with

```
new Date()
```

start with

```
new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5))
```

This will give you a `Date` instance that represents your required point in time. You don't need to change any other part of your code.

Answer (score 24):

Ignoring `Dates` and focusing on the question.

My preference is to use `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit` since it adds clarity to my code.

In Java,

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

5 minutes from `now` using `TimeUtil` is:

```
long nowPlus5Minutes = now + TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5);
```

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html

Answer (score 16):

You should use [**Calendar class**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) to manipulate Date and time:

> The Calendar class is an abstract class that provides methods for
>   converting between a specific instant in time and a set of calendar
>   fields such as YEAR, MONTH, DAY_OF_MONTH, HOUR, and so on, and for
>   manipulating the calendar fields, such as getting the date of the next
>   week

```
  Date dNow = new Date( ); // Instantiate a Date object
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  cal.setTime(dNow);
  cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
  dNow = cal.getTime();
```

Comment: You should never use the Calendar class for anything.  Use Joda time for these manipulations.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen well, i hear ppl saying this all the time. I have personally never use Joda time.I have heard it makes date manipulating pretty simple. but if you wanna manipulate dates using standard API then calendar is the way to go. However, i have read somewhere that Joda time would be part of standard java API from java 8. :)

Comment: It is the [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) and it will not be a completely new API, only heavily influenced by JodaTime.

Comment: @PermGenError You should listen to what all these people say all the time and try using it and then consider how the better design of the API makes it easier to do what you actually want (and do it correct)

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen hehe, i never really had a requirement to do complex date/time manipulating stuff. as i said for simple date/time manipulation as such external API is not required, infact for problem as simple as this it has to be handled as show in mark's answer.:), thanks though, i will look into joda time .. :)

Answer (score 7):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.now()
       .plusSeconds( TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds( 5 ) )
       .toString()
```

> 2017-01-23T03:11:53.763Z

## Details

The other Answers are outdated as of Java 8. The troublesome old date-time classes are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

This class can do math such as adding a number of seconds. We can use the [`TimeUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) enum to covert our desired five minutes into a number of seconds.

```
long seconds = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds( 5 );
Instant fiveMinutesLater = instant.plusSeconds( seconds );
```

To generate a string in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, call `toString`.

```
String output = fiveMinutesLater.toString();
```

To generate strings in other formats, use the `ZonedDateTime` class and `DateTimeFormatter` class. Search Stack Overflow for many examples and discussions of those classes.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 5):

Use this ...

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
    calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
    System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Date dNow = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+5*60*1000)
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("MMM d, yyyy k:mm:ss");
System.out.println(ft.format(dNow));
```

with the help of deprecated method `getMinutes(),setMinutes(int)`

```
 Date dNow = new Date( ); // Instantiate a Date object
 int mm = dNow.getMinutes();
 dNow.setMinutes(mm+5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Java dates use [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) in milliseconds. So you either calculate how much 5 minutes are in milliseconds and add them to your date or use the Calendar class which does it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one best performance

```
    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
            gc.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            gc.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -5);
            System.out.println(new java.util.Date().getTime());
            System.out.println(new java.util.Date(gc.getTime().getTime()).getTime());
```